# Property Naming Convention

Tags: php, naming-conventions, redbean

Paging Gabor de Mooij or anybody else who have been more experienced with RedBeanPHP. The current naming convention we have is using underscores and although anybody can make a case of using Pascal/Camel casing I think what's important is consistency and we don't want to refactor everything to just to conform to a consistent naming pattern but we'll see what we can do.

There's just these statements that are contradicting. Can anybody clarify this rule?

[image]

Also, don't you think 2 or more worded properties are also common and its ugly if they are all in lowercase: date_added or dateAdded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RedBeanPHP has been designed for an 'agile' approach. The database gets crafted by RedBeanPHP on-the-fly, while you are coding the app and discussing the domain with your customer.

However I will never impose artificial limitations. You can use underscores and uppercase characters, just remember that RedBeanPHP uses some conventions to retrieve/store relations: table_id and table1_table2 are the most important ones.

Also note that uppercase table names can be very hard to maintain because some database-OS combinations are case-insensitive.

As of RedBeanPHP 3.4 (now alpha) RedBeanPHP will throw an exception if you try to store a bean with an invalid type name; however this is just to warn you. To override this check use setStricTyping(false).

Example:

```
R::setStrictTyping(false);
$bean = R::dispense('postAddress');
$bean->housenumber = '1';
R::store($bean);
$bean = R::dispense('post_address');
$bean->house_number = '2';
R::store($bean);
```

This will just work.

I hope this clarifies the situation, I will update the docs to be more specific as soon as I have some time. Thank you for notifying me about this issue. Feel free to ask any question on our forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/redbeanorm

Note that your first message needs to be approved on the forum; however there was no other way to keep the spam away..

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions you can use underscores in property types, but wasn't recommended as it could possibly conflict with the foreign keys.  I am not sure about the latest version forbidding it or just not recommending it.  The statements are contradictory, but again, I think you are able to use the underscores, it just isn't recommended.

In previous versions, all foreign keys are named `<TABLENAME>_id` and are accessed by `$bean->TABLENAME->TABLEPROPERTY`

Table names are linked in many-to-many relationships with an underscore `<TABLE1>_<TABLE2>`.

I am pretty sure the newest version of redbean is the same as older versions in that you *can*, but it could cause complications if you have `****_id` as a property or combine two table names using an underscore.

As far as I know, those are the only two instances where problems could happen.  I am not sure about tags or other properties.

Comment: how about the a 2 or more worded properties? they are restricted to have underscores or camel/pascal casing?